# How do I convert a TimeSpan to a formatted string?

Tags: c#, timespan

I have two DateTime vars, beginTime and endTime. I have gotten the difference of them by doing the following:

```
TimeSpan dateDifference = endTime.Subtract(beginTime);
```

How can I now return a string of this in hh hrs, mm mins, ss secs format using C#.

If the difference was 00:06:32.4458750

It should return this 00 hrs, 06 mins, 32 secs

Comment: For a more modern answer go to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574881/how-can-i-string-format-a-timespan-object-with-a-custom-format-in-net

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Would [TimeSpan.ToString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ecy8h51.aspx) do the trick for you? If not, it looks like the code sample on that page describes how to do custom formatting of a `TimeSpan` object.

Comment: I got the same, searched again and updated the link. Does this one work for you?

Comment: That page does **not** describe how a programmer can format the TimeSpan string at will. It only describes the format in which the TimeSpan is returned when converted with ToString(). That ToString() does not take any custom arguments like "mm:ss". The code samples only show how the auto-generated string will look like given different TimeSpan values, **not** how to format it at will. You need to convert to DateTime(TimeSpan.Ticks).ToString("mm:ss") first.

Comment: I converted it in this way => timespan.tostring("%d") + " " +timespan.tostring(@"hh\:mm:\ss"); . The idea is get the required strings separately and join them.

Comment: FYI since .Net 4.0, the `ToString` method **can** take a custom format as an argument (like `mm\\:ss`), according to this page : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992632.aspx

Comment: For more options: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: The linked article does not include code with any ToString() calls....

Answer (score 212):

I just built a few TimeSpan Extension methods. Thought I could share:

```
public static string ToReadableAgeString(this TimeSpan span)
{
    return string.Format("{0:0}", span.Days / 365.25);
}

public static string ToReadableString(this TimeSpan span)
{
    string formatted = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}",
        span.Duration().Days > 0 ? string.Format("{0:0} day{1}, ", span.Days, span.Days == 1 ? string.Empty : "s") : string.Empty,
        span.Duration().Hours > 0 ? string.Format("{0:0} hour{1}, ", span.Hours, span.Hours == 1 ? string.Empty : "s") : string.Empty,
        span.Duration().Minutes > 0 ? string.Format("{0:0} minute{1}, ", span.Minutes, span.Minutes == 1 ? string.Empty : "s") : string.Empty,
        span.Duration().Seconds > 0 ? string.Format("{0:0} second{1}", span.Seconds, span.Seconds == 1 ? string.Empty : "s") : string.Empty);

    if (formatted.EndsWith(", ")) formatted = formatted.Substring(0, formatted.Length - 2);

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(formatted)) formatted = "0 seconds";

    return formatted;
}
```

Comment: What if I don't want to show seconds or days. Not very `extensible` :( but it is certainly the correct direction, you should accept a string like "hh:mm" in here and build the time based on that. Just like `ToString()` I think the answer by @rubenroid is the best answer.

Comment: @ppumkin His answer displays the result in a totally fixed format. This answer will handle the sensible display of 1 second, right up to hundreds of days. His answer doesn't.

Comment: If you only want to display the most important part of `TimeSpan` like "2 days ago" or "15 minutes ago" then check this gist inspired by @Peter anwear: https://gist.github.com/Rychu-Pawel/fefb89e21b764e97e4993ff517ff0129

Comment: @Rychu Your code requires C# 8.0.

Answer (score 158):

By converting it to a datetime, you can get localized formats:

```
new DateTime(timeSpan.Ticks).ToString("HH:mm");
```

Comment: Be sure to use a "HH", not "hh", as a format specifier, otherwise an hours value of 0 might be printed out as "12" - I'm guessing the interpretation of the format specifiers depends on the locale settings.

Comment: Also, this has the same issue as Guffa's - if an elapsed time is e.g. 26 hours long, it prints out as "02:00" hours.  But I highly prefer this way of printing out formatted strings.

Comment: I needed a one-liner to use in a VB expression. This was perfect.

Comment: This method will cause problems if the timespan is negative.

Comment: This doesn't work with "d" days. If you use DateTime then days is always `1`.

Answer (score 150):

This is the shortest solution.

```
timeSpan.ToString(@"hh\:mm");
```

Comment: This has a bug. timespan is 1 day, 0 hours and 33 minutes, it will return 00:33 even though it is 24:33 technically.

Comment: @RickRatayczak Imo I wouldn't call it a bug, considering this would, in most cases, be used to display an elapsed time between two timespans. Which rarely exceeds a whole day.
Regardless, I see your point, and if that's the case, this solution simply isn't for you.

I think it's brilliant though.

Comment: That's because the format string in the answer doesn't specify the value of the days component of the time span to be shown; 24 hours rolls over into 1 day. Not a bug, its just not showing.

Comment: timeSpan.ToString(@"d\:hh\:mm");

Comment: If you want an output above 24 hours you can do something like this..

TimeSpan span = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(13425);
string hours = string.Format("{0:00}", Math.Round(span.TotalHours, 0));
string minutes = string.Format("{0:00}", span.Minutes); 
string output = string.Format("{0}:{1}", hours, minutes);

Comment: @BjarkeSøgaard I agree that it's not a bug, if you want to show the day you have to include it in the format string, but where does the assumption come from that the TimeSpan difference between two DateTimes rarely exceeds a whole day?

Comment: From C# Interactive window:
 new TimeSpan(12, 12, 12).ToString(@"HH\:mm")
Input string was not in a correct format.
  + System.Globalization.TimeSpanFormat.FormatCustomized(System.TimeSpan, string, System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo)
  + System.Globalization.TimeSpanFormat.Format(System.TimeSpan, string, System.IFormatProvider)
  + System.TimeSpan.ToString(string)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It helps me.

Comment: A slightly different expression: `timeSpan.ToString("hh\\:mm");`

Answer (score 37):

Use String.Format() with multiple parameters.

```
using System;

namespace TimeSpanFormat
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TimeSpan dateDifference = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 6, 32, 445);
            string formattedTimeSpan = string.Format("{0:D2} hrs, {1:D2} mins, {2:D2} secs", dateDifference.Hours, dateDifference.Minutes, dateDifference.Seconds);
            Console.WriteLine(formattedTimeSpan);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14):

```
   public static class TimeSpanFormattingExtensions
   {
      public static string ToReadableString(this TimeSpan span)
      {
         return string.Join(", ", span.GetReadableStringElements()
            .Where(str => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str)));
      }

      private static IEnumerable<string> GetReadableStringElements(this TimeSpan span)
      {
         yield return GetDaysString((int)Math.Floor(span.TotalDays));
         yield return GetHoursString(span.Hours);
         yield return GetMinutesString(span.Minutes);
         yield return GetSecondsString(span.Seconds);
      }

      private static string GetDaysString(int days)
      {
         if (days == 0)
            return string.Empty;

         if (days == 1)
            return "1 day";

         return string.Format("{0:0} days", days);
      }

      private static string GetHoursString(int hours)
      {
         if (hours == 0)
            return string.Empty;

         if (hours == 1)
            return "1 hour";

         return string.Format("{0:0} hours", hours);
      }

      private static string GetMinutesString(int minutes)
      {
         if (minutes == 0)
            return string.Empty;

         if (minutes == 1)
            return "1 minute";

         return string.Format("{0:0} minutes", minutes);
      }

      private static string GetSecondsString(int seconds)
      {
         if (seconds == 0)
            return string.Empty;

         if (seconds == 1)
            return "1 second";

         return string.Format("{0:0} seconds", seconds);
      }
   }
```

Comment: Just the answer I needed. Displays the timespan is a very much readable format..

Answer (score 8):

The easiest way to format a `TimeSpan` is to add it to a `DateTime` and format that:

```
string formatted = (DateTime.Today + dateDifference).ToString("HH 'hrs' mm 'mins' ss 'secs'");
```

This works as long as the time difference is not more than 24 hours.

The `Today` property returns a `DateTime` value where the time component is zero, so the time component of the result is the `TimeSpan` value.

Comment: I think this is the most simple approach.  You might want to remove zero hours and minutes like:

.ToString("HH 'hrs' mm 'mins' ss 'secs'").Replace("00 hrs", "").Replace("00 mins", "").Trim()

Answer (score 6):

According to [the Microsoft documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.days.aspx), the TimeSpan structure exposes Hours, Minutes, Seconds, and Milliseconds as integer members. Maybe you want something like:

```
dateDifference.Hours.ToString() + " hrs, " + dateDifference.Minutes.ToString() + " mins, " + dateDifference.Seconds.ToString() + " secs"
```

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to Peter for the extension method.  I modified it to work with longer time spans better:

```
namespace ExtensionMethods
{
    public static class TimeSpanExtensionMethods
    {
        public static string ToReadableString(this TimeSpan span)
        {
            string formatted = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}",
                (span.Days / 7) > 0 ? string.Format("{0:0} weeks, ", span.Days / 7) : string.Empty,
                span.Days % 7 > 0 ? string.Format("{0:0} days, ", span.Days % 7) : string.Empty,
                span.Hours > 0 ? string.Format("{0:0} hours, ", span.Hours) : string.Empty);

            if (formatted.EndsWith(", ")) formatted = formatted.Substring(0, formatted.Length - 2);

            return formatted;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can Years be added too ?But I think it will not be accurate to add years

Answer (score 5):

You can use the following code.

```
public static class TimeSpanExtensions
{
  public static String Verbose(this TimeSpan timeSpan)
  {
    var hours = timeSpan.Hours;
    var minutes = timeSpan.Minutes;

    if (hours > 0) return String.Format("{0} hours {1} minutes", hours, minutes);
    return String.Format("{0} minutes", minutes);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I also had a similar issue and came up with my own extension but it seems to be a bit different than everything else.

```
    public static string TimeSpanToString(this TimeSpan timeSpan)
    {
        //if it's negative
        if (timeSpan.Ticks < 0)
        {
            timeSpan = timeSpan - timeSpan - timeSpan;
            if (timeSpan.Days != 0)
                return string.Format("-{0}:{1}", timeSpan.Days.ToString("d"), new DateTime(timeSpan.Ticks).ToString("HH:mm:ss"));
            else
                return new DateTime(timeSpan.Ticks).ToString("-HH:mm:ss");
        }

        //if it has days
        else if (timeSpan.Days != 0)
            return string.Format("{0}:{1}", timeSpan.Days.ToString("d"), new DateTime(timeSpan.Ticks).ToString("HH:mm:ss"));

        //otherwise return the time
        else
            return new DateTime(timeSpan.Ticks).ToString("HH:mm:ss");
    }
```

Comment: calling this `timeSpan = timeSpan - timeSpan - timeSpan;` as different is an insult to different :-) but I like it, in a perverse sort of way

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is older but .Net 4 now has support for [Custom TimeSpan formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287.aspx).

Also I know it's been mentioned but it caught me out, converting Ticks to DateTime works but doesn't properly handle more than a 24 hour span.

```
new DateTime((DateTime.Now - DateTime.Now.AddHours(-25)).Ticks).ToString("HH:mm")
```

That will get you 01:00 not 25:00 as you might expect.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a late answer but this works for me:

```
TimeSpan dateDifference = new TimeSpan(0,0,0, (int)endTime.Subtract(beginTime).TotalSeconds);
```

dateDifference should now exclude the parts smaller than a second. Works in .net 2.0 too.

Answer (score -14):

```
''' <summary>
''' Return specified Double # (NumDbl) as String using specified Number Format String (FormatStr, 
''' Default = "N0") and Format Provider (FmtProvider, Default = Nothing) followed by space and,  
''' if NumDbl = 1, the specified Singular Unit Name (SglUnitStr), else the Plural Unit Name 
''' (PluralUnitStr).
''' </summary>
''' <param name="NumDbl"></param>
''' <param name="SglUnitStr"></param>
''' <param name="PluralUnitStr"></param>
''' <param name="FormatStr"></param>
''' <param name="FmtProvider"></param>
''' <returns></returns>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Public Function PluralizeUnitsStr( _
    ByVal NumDbl As Double, _
    ByVal SglUnitStr As String, _
    ByVal PluralUnitStr As String, _
    Optional ByVal FormatStr As String = "N0", _
    Optional ByVal FmtProvider As System.IFormatProvider = Nothing _
    ) As String

    PluralizeUnitsStr = NumDbl.ToString(FormatStr, FmtProvider) & " "

    Dim RsltUnitStr As String

    If NumDbl = 1 Then
        RsltUnitStr = SglUnitStr
    Else
        RsltUnitStr = PluralUnitStr
    End If

    PluralizeUnitsStr &= RsltUnitStr

End Function

''' <summary>
''' Info about a # Unit.
''' </summary>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Public Class clsNumUnitInfoItem
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Name of a Singular Unit (i.e. "day", "trillion", "foot")
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public UnitSglStr As String

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Name of a Plural Unit (i.e. "days", "trillion", "feet")
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public UnitPluralStr As String

    ''' <summary>
    ''' # of Units to = 1 of Next Higher (aka Parent) Unit (i.e. 24 "hours", 1000 "million", 
    ''' 5280 "feet")
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public UnitsInParentInt As Integer
End Class ' -- clsNumUnitInfoItem

Dim TimeLongEnUnitInfoItms As clsNumUnitInfoItem() = { _
    New clsNumUnitInfoItem With {.UnitSglStr = "day", .UnitPluralStr = "days", .UnitsInParentInt = 1}, _
    New clsNumUnitInfoItem With {.UnitSglStr = "hour", .UnitPluralStr = "hours", .UnitsInParentInt = 24}, _
    New clsNumUnitInfoItem With {.UnitSglStr = "minute", .UnitPluralStr = "minutes", .UnitsInParentInt = 60}, _
    New clsNumUnitInfoItem With {.UnitSglStr = "second", .UnitPluralStr = "seconds", .UnitsInParentInt = 60}, _
    New clsNumUnitInfoItem With {.UnitSglStr = "millisecond", .UnitPluralStr = "milliseconds", .UnitsInParentInt = 1000} _
    } ' -- Dim TimeLongEnUnitInfoItms

Dim TimeShortEnUnitInfoItms As clsNumUnitInfoItem() = { _
    New clsNumUnitInfoItem With {.UnitSglStr = "day", .UnitPluralStr = "days", .UnitsInParentInt = 1}, _
    New clsNumUnitInfoItem With {.UnitSglStr = "hr", .UnitPluralStr = "hrs", .UnitsInParentInt = 24}, _
    New clsNumUnitInfoItem With {.UnitSglStr = "min", .UnitPluralStr = "mins", .UnitsInParentInt = 60}, _
    New clsNumUnitInfoItem With {.UnitSglStr = "sec", .UnitPluralStr = "secs", .UnitsInParentInt = 60}, _
    New clsNumUnitInfoItem With {.UnitSglStr = "msec", .UnitPluralStr = "msecs", .UnitsInParentInt = 1000} _
    } ' -- Dim TimeShortEnUnitInfoItms

''' <summary>
''' Convert a specified Double Number (NumDbl) to a long (aka verbose) format (i.e. "1 day, 
''' 2 hours, 3 minutes, 4 seconds and 567 milliseconds") with a specified Array of Time Unit 
''' Info Items (TimeUnitInfoItms), Conjunction (ConjStr, Default = "and"), Minimum Unit Level 
''' Shown (MinUnitLevInt) (0 to TimeUnitInfoItms.Length - 1, -1=All), Maximum Unit Level Shown 
''' (MaxUnitLevInt) (-1=All), Maximum # of Unit Levels Shown (MaxNumUnitLevsInt) (1 to 0 to 
''' TimeUnitInfoItms.Length - 1, 0=All) and Round Last Shown Units Up Flag (RoundUpBool).  
''' Suppress leading 0 Unit Levels.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="NumDbl"></param>
''' <param name="NumUnitInfoItms"></param>
''' <param name="ConjStr"></param>
''' <param name="MinUnitLevInt"></param>
''' <param name="MaxUnitLevInt"></param>
''' <param name="MaxNumUnitLevsInt"></param>
''' <param name="RoundUpBool"></param>
''' <param name="FormatStr"></param>
''' <param name="FmtProvider"></param>
''' <returns></returns>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Public Function NumToLongStr( _
    ByVal NumDbl As Double, _
    ByVal NumUnitInfoItms As clsNumUnitInfoItem(), _
    Optional ByVal ConjStr As String = "and", _
    Optional ByVal MinUnitLevInt As Integer = -1, _
    Optional ByVal MaxUnitLevInt As Integer = -1, _
    Optional ByVal MaxNumUnitLevsInt As Integer = 0, _
    Optional ByVal RoundUpBool As Boolean = False, _
    Optional ByVal FormatStr As String = "N0", _
    Optional ByVal FmtProvider As System.IFormatProvider = Nothing _
    ) As String
    NumToLongStr = ""

    Const TUnitDelimStr As String = ", "

    If (MinUnitLevInt < -1) OrElse (MinUnitLevInt >= NumUnitInfoItms.Length) Then
        Throw New Exception("Invalid MinUnitLevInt: " & MaxUnitLevInt)
    End If

    If (MaxUnitLevInt < -1) OrElse (MaxUnitLevInt >= NumUnitInfoItms.Length) Then
        Throw New Exception("Invalid MaxDetailLevelInt: " & MaxUnitLevInt)
    End If

    If (MaxNumUnitLevsInt < 0) OrElse (MaxNumUnitLevsInt > NumUnitInfoItms.Length) Then
        Throw New Exception("Invalid MaxNumUnitLevsInt: " & MaxNumUnitLevsInt)
    End If

    Dim PrevNumUnitsDbl As Double = NumDbl
    Dim CurrUnitLevInt As Integer = -1
    Dim NumUnitLevsShownInt As Integer = 0

    For Each UnitInfoItem In NumUnitInfoItms
        CurrUnitLevInt += 1

        With UnitInfoItem

            Dim CurrNumUnitsDbl As Double = PrevNumUnitsDbl * .UnitsInParentInt
            Dim CurrTruncNumUnitsInt As Integer = Math.Truncate(CurrNumUnitsDbl)
            PrevNumUnitsDbl = CurrNumUnitsDbl
            If CurrUnitLevInt < MinUnitLevInt Then Continue For
            PrevNumUnitsDbl -= CurrTruncNumUnitsInt

            'If (CurrUnitLevInt > TimeUnitInfoItms.Length) _
            '    OrElse _
            '    ( _
            '    (CurrUnitLevInt > MaxUnitLevInt) AndAlso _
            '    (MaxUnitLevInt <> -1) _
            '    ) _
            '    OrElse _
            '    ( _
            '    (NumUnitLevsShownInt + 1 > MaxNumUnitLevsInt) AndAlso _
            '    (MaxNumUnitLevsInt <> 0) _
            '    ) Then Exit For

            If (CurrUnitLevInt = (NumUnitInfoItms.Length - 1)) OrElse _
                (CurrUnitLevInt = MaxUnitLevInt) OrElse _
                ((NumUnitLevsShownInt + 1) = MaxNumUnitLevsInt) Then

                If NumUnitLevsShownInt > 0 Then
                    Dim TUnitDelimStrLenInt As Integer = TUnitDelimStr.Length
                    NumToLongStr = NumToLongStr.Remove( _
                        NumToLongStr.Length - TUnitDelimStrLenInt, _
                        TUnitDelimStrLenInt)
                    NumToLongStr &= " " & ConjStr & " "
                End If

                Dim CurrNunUnitsRoundedInt As Integer
                If RoundUpBool Then
                    If CurrNumUnitsDbl <> CurrTruncNumUnitsInt Then
                        CurrNunUnitsRoundedInt = CurrTruncNumUnitsInt + 1
                    Else
                        CurrNunUnitsRoundedInt = CurrTruncNumUnitsInt
                    End If
                Else
                    CurrNunUnitsRoundedInt = Math.Round( _
                        value:=CurrNumUnitsDbl, mode:=MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
                End If

                NumToLongStr &= _
                    PluralizeUnitsStr(CurrNunUnitsRoundedInt, _
                        .UnitSglStr, .UnitPluralStr, FormatStr, FmtProvider)
                Exit For

            Else ' -- Not (MaxUnitLevInt or MaxNumUnitLevsInt)

                If NumUnitLevsShownInt > 0 OrElse CurrTruncNumUnitsInt <> 0 Then
                    NumToLongStr &= _
                        PluralizeUnitsStr(CurrTruncNumUnitsInt, _
                            .UnitSglStr, .UnitPluralStr, FormatStr, FmtProvider) & _
                        TUnitDelimStr
                    NumUnitLevsShownInt += 1
                End If

            End If ' -- Else Not (MaxUnitLevInt or MaxNumUnitLevsInt)

        End With ' -- UnitInfoItem

    Next UnitInfoItem

End Function

''' <summary>
''' Call NumToLongStr with a specified TimeSpan's (TS) TotalDays.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="TS"></param>
''' <param name="TimeUnitInfoItms"></param>
''' <param name="ConjStr"></param>
''' <param name="MinUnitLevInt"></param>
''' <param name="MaxUnitLevInt"></param>
''' <param name="MaxNumUnitLevsInt"></param>
''' <param name="RoundUpBool"></param>
''' <param name="FormatStr"></param>
''' <param name="FmtProvider"></param>
''' <returns></returns>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Public Function TimeSpanToStr( _
    ByVal TS As TimeSpan, _
    ByVal TimeUnitInfoItms As clsNumUnitInfoItem(), _
    Optional ByVal ConjStr As String = "and", _
    Optional ByVal MinUnitLevInt As Integer = -1, _
    Optional ByVal MaxUnitLevInt As Integer = -1, _
    Optional ByVal MaxNumUnitLevsInt As Integer = 0, _
    Optional ByVal RoundUpBool As Boolean = False, _
    Optional ByVal FormatStr As String = "N0", _
    Optional ByVal FmtProvider As System.IFormatProvider = Nothing _
    ) As String

    Return NumToLongStr( _
        NumDbl:=TS.TotalDays, _
        NumUnitInfoItms:=TimeUnitInfoItms, _
        ConjStr:=ConjStr, _
        MinUnitLevInt:=MinUnitLevInt, _
        MaxUnitLevInt:=MaxUnitLevInt, _
        MaxNumUnitLevsInt:=MaxNumUnitLevsInt, _
        RoundUpBool:=RoundUpBool, _
        FormatStr:=FormatStr, _
        FmtProvider:=FmtProvider _
        )

End Function

''' <summary>
''' Call TimeSpanToStr with TimeLongEnUnitInfoItms.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="TS"></param>
''' <param name="MinUnitLevInt"></param>
''' <param name="MaxUnitLevInt"></param>
''' <param name="MaxNumUnitLevsInt"></param>
''' <param name="RoundUpBool"></param>
''' <param name="FormatStr"></param>
''' <param name="FmtProvider"></param>
''' <returns></returns>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Public Function TimeSpanToLongEnStr( _
    ByVal TS As TimeSpan, _
    Optional ByVal MinUnitLevInt As Integer = -1, _
    Optional ByVal MaxUnitLevInt As Integer = -1, _
    Optional ByVal MaxNumUnitLevsInt As Integer = 0, _
    Optional ByVal RoundUpBool As Boolean = False, _
    Optional ByVal FormatStr As String = "N0", _
    Optional ByVal FmtProvider As System.IFormatProvider = Nothing _
    ) As String

    Return TimeSpanToStr( _
        TS:=TS, _
        TimeUnitInfoItms:=TimeLongEnUnitInfoItms, _
        MinUnitLevInt:=MinUnitLevInt, _
        MaxUnitLevInt:=MaxUnitLevInt, _
        MaxNumUnitLevsInt:=MaxNumUnitLevsInt, _
        RoundUpBool:=RoundUpBool, _
        FormatStr:=FormatStr, _
        FmtProvider:=FmtProvider _
        )
End Function
```

Comment: That's VB. The question asks for C#.

Comment: @Stephen Kennedy: Really???  [link](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/)

Comment: @user401246 you should've run it through that converter, tested it and put the c# code here instead. As it is, your answer isn't very useful.

Comment: 1) With all due respect, if *I* were him and someone saved *me* this much coding with the only caveat being that I'd have to copy and paste it into a converter first, *I* would be extremely grateful.  If someone from another country gave you the formula to cold fusion, are you just gonna critique him for not giving it to you in your language when a translation is just a couple of clicks away?!?  2) I do not work in C#, so it would not be fitting for me to "test" it in C#.  I'm offering what I can easily offer (for free).  3) The O.P. didn't complain.  Let him speak for himself.

Comment: That is allot of code! ?? What is going on in there? IF a developer wrote this for me I would be forced to cry.

Comment: "allot of code" relative to what?!?  In case you didn't notice, it is MUCH, MUCH more flexible (i.e. supporting diff abbrevs, other types of #'s, other languages, etc.) than any of the above solutions.  Granted it's way more flexible than what the OP needed but IMHO, not unreasonably so from the perspective of being plopped in a shared lib that could be used in other places in his / other apps.

Comment: @ppumkin indeed that's a lot of code.