# Calculating time in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, datetime, timespan

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I calculate relative time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11/how-do-i-calculate-relative-time)

While posting something on SO it shows posted `5 mins ago` or `1hr ago`. How do I calculate the time and display it the same way?

Comment: @Daniel - I need the logic to try. I am not asking for code am just asking for hint to get started.

Comment: this could get you going: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/842057/how-do-i-convert-a-timespan-to-a-formatted-string

Comment: You can take 2 DateTime instances and subtract them like this: TimeSpan result = firstDateTimeInstance - secondDateTimeInstance;

Answer (score 8):

For example [C# Pretty Date Formatting](http://www.dotnetperls.com/pretty-date):

```
    static string GetPrettyDate(DateTime d)
    {
    // 1.
    // Get time span elapsed since the date.
    TimeSpan s = DateTime.Now.Subtract(d);

    // 2.
    // Get total number of days elapsed.
    int dayDiff = (int)s.TotalDays;

    // 3.
    // Get total number of seconds elapsed.
    int secDiff = (int)s.TotalSeconds;

    // 4.
    // Don't allow out of range values.
    if (dayDiff < 0 || dayDiff >= 31)
    {
        return null;
    }

    // 5.
    // Handle same-day times.
    if (dayDiff == 0)
    {
        // A.
        // Less than one minute ago.
        if (secDiff < 60)
        {
        return "just now";
        }
        // B.
        // Less than 2 minutes ago.
        if (secDiff < 120)
        {
        return "1 minute ago";
        }
        // C.
        // Less than one hour ago.
        if (secDiff < 3600)
        {
        return string.Format("{0} minutes ago",
            Math.Floor((double)secDiff / 60));
        }
        // D.
        // Less than 2 hours ago.
        if (secDiff < 7200)
        {
        return "1 hour ago";
        }
        // E.
        // Less than one day ago.
        if (secDiff < 86400)
        {
        return string.Format("{0} hours ago",
            Math.Floor((double)secDiff / 3600));
        }
    }
    // 6.
    // Handle previous days.
    if (dayDiff == 1)
    {
        return "yesterday";
    }
    if (dayDiff < 7)
    {
        return string.Format("{0} days ago",
        dayDiff);
    }
    if (dayDiff < 31)
    {
        return string.Format("{0} weeks ago",
        Math.Ceiling((double)dayDiff / 7));
    }
    return null;
    }
```

(And you can also use a jquery plugin named [Prettydate](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-prettydate/).)