# difference between 2 ajax popup calendars

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 2 textboxes with 2 ajax calendars.One is start date and the other is end date. I'm trying to find the days between them but I can't seem to get it right.This is how I do it:

```
string a = txt1.Text;
        string b = txt2.Text;


        DateTime data1 = Convert.ToDateTime(a);
        DateTime data2 = Convert.ToDateTime(b);

        TimeSpan span = data2 - data1;

        int zile = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling(span.TotalDays));

        label.Text = span.ToString();
```

The dates from my textboxes are in this format: 4/4/2012 and 4/5/2012. This should be one day difference but when I run this code it brings up 30 day because it's interpreted as one month..How can I change that???

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me, just tested it.

```
using System;

namespace DaySpan
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            DateTime startDate = DateTime.Parse("03.04.2012");
            DateTime endDate = DateTime.Parse("06.04.2012");

            Console.WriteLine(startDate.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(endDate.ToString());

            Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("Calculate dayspan:");

            TimeSpan span = endDate - startDate;

            Console.WriteLine("Span: " + span.TotalDays);

            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    } 
}
```

EDIT: This may though a problem as mentioned in top post with datetime parsing and locale. However this is correct with my locale (norwegian).

Comment: yea works for me too... or you can do span.Days; instead of span.TotalDays

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't that result indicate 92 days 0 hrs, 0 mins, 0 secs?  I guess I don't see the problem here.

Edit - If you are wanting that to give you just the days property, take a look at [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/842057/how-do-i-convert-a-timespan-to-a-formatted-string)

Comment: but it's only a difference of 3 days

Comment: You mean 3 months?  6/4/2012 - 3/4/2012 = 3 months (in this case 92 days)

Comment: my format from textboxes are in this format: 04/03/2012 and 04/06/2012