# How to format Timespan object to string

Tags: c#, timespan

I'm looking for the following format:
`00:00:00`

Using the section as a reference [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372286.aspx#GeneralShort). This should technically work `.ToString("hh:mm:ss")` but it is complaining there is a syntax error.

**Note:** `ToString("g")` is close but gives me this format `0:0:0.0000...`. I want the formatter to either truncate or round if the value in question is not a whole number.

Comment: You can read all about custom `TimeSpan` format strings here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287.aspx.

Comment: string s = new TimeSpan(10000001).ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/842057/how-do-i-convert-a-timespan-to-a-formatted-string (which is also  a duplicate!)

Comment: @ElVieejo Which none of the answers answer my question like Jmyster or Bjorn has.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
ToString("hh':'mm':'ss")
```

Should also work:

```
ToString("c")
```

Comment: it's for the literal charecter ":". ToString recognizes the hh mm ss. You have to tell it what you want inbetween. I literally want to put a : here.

Comment: When you apply the same formatter to a DateTime object why don't you have to use the literal character?

Comment: @Nick: It is explained in more detail on the MSDN page I have linked in a comment to the question.

Comment: @Nick: The ' is just escaping the :, since that is a keyword in the format string. You can also use `string.Format("{0:hh}:{0:mm}:{0:ss}, ts);` for instance, in which you see why the : needs to be escaped.

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax is almost correct, this works: `ToString("hh\\:mm\\:ss");`

Comment: Or use a verbatim string literal: `@"hh\:mm\:ss"` (I'd recommend it for the same reason it's widely used for regex strings)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have `TimeSpan ts`;

**Then try:**

```
String.Format("{0} {1} {2}", ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds);
```