# Formatting subtracted dates c#

Tags: c#, datetime, formatting

I am trying to subtract two dates from each other in c#. My current code looks like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.DateTime matchStart = new System.DateTime(2012, 10, 17, 20, 00, 00);
    System.DateTime currentDateTime = new System.DateTime(2012, 10, 9, 14, 00, 00);

    System.TimeSpan matchCountdown = matchStart.Subtract(currentDateTime);

    countdown.Text = matchCountdown.ToString();
}
```

This currently gives me the result "8.06:00:00". What I am trying to do however, is to get the time difference formatted so it says "8 days, 6 hours, 0 minutes". How on earth do I get on about doing this?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: You can use the `-` minus operator, no need to call the `Subtract` method.

Comment: Take a look at this answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/842057/how-do-i-convert-a-timespan-to-a-formatted-string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `String.Format` and the [`TimeSpan` properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/02c79d34.aspx).

```
String.Format("{0} days, {1} hours, {2} minutes"
    , matchCountdown.Days
    , matchCountdown.Hours
    , matchCountdown.Minutes);
```

Here's the demo: http://ideone.com/i8SKX

Comment: Need to truncate those doubles.

Comment: @spender agreed, should probably `"{0:n0} days, {1:n0} hours, {2:n0} minutes"`

Comment: @spender: The properties above like [`TimeSpan.Days`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.days.aspx) are all `ints`. Have   [a look](http://ideone.com/i8SKX).