# Windows Phone : How to set a string as a TimeSpanPicker value?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am using TimeSpanPicker in my application. Default value of the textbox in the TimeSpanPicker is something like "00:00:00" which its type is TimeSpan.

```
enter code here

 TimeSpanPicker ts = new TimeSpanPicker ();
 ts.Value = TimeSpan.Parse("00:00:00");
```

I am trying to change the value of timespanpicker to a string but I face with an error. How can I solve this problem?

Thanks,B

Comment: what error are you seeing?

Comment: FormatEXception was unhandled by user code                               An exception of type 'system.FormatException' occured in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Answer (score 0):

Would TimeSpan.ToString() do the trick for you? else this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/842057/how-do-i-convert-a-timespan-to-a-formatted-string) might help u as well

Comment: we dont have something like TimeSpan.ToString()