# Convert a decimal value to time format in c#

Tags: c#

I am currently taking 2 dates from a database and finding the difference between them. I am displaying the value from the sum in my view page but it is currently showing as a decimal. For example, one of the values that gets produced is 1585.913 but I would like that in HH:MM:SS format.

My current code that displays the decimal value is as follows.

### Controller

```
public ActionResult Execution(int id = 0)
    {
        Execution execution = db.Executions.Find(id);

        if (execution == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        ViewBag.ExecutionSeconds = (execution.End - execution.Start).TotalSeconds;

        return View(execution);

    }
```

### View

```
@ViewBag.ExecutionSeconds
```

What changes to this code would I have to make in order for it to display the value in HH:MM:SS format?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `1585.913` is second?

Comment: Please explain more clearly how you want the "conversion" done.  Is `1585.913` supposed to be in seconds?  Adding an example with expected output would be really helpful.

Comment: yes, it is in seconds. So i expect something along the lines of 00:26:26

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `.ToString()` method to format your `TimeSpan`. For example :

```
(execution.End - execution.Start).ToString(@"dd\.hh\:mm\:ss");
```

More information :

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 4):

Substractions of two dates returns structure of type [TimeSpan](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

```
(execution.End - execution.Start);// returns TimeSpan
(execution.End - execution.Start).ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss"); // format it
```

[Timespan formatting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

if your time is bigger than 24 hours (as @juharr pointed) you can use

```
string.Format("{0}:{1}:{2}", (int)time.TotalHours, time.Minutes, time.Seconds);
```

or include days by replacing formatting string with `@"dd\.hh\:mm\:ss"`

I'd add an extension for TimeSpan, since such formatting happens pretty often (coppied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/842057/how-do-i-convert-a-timespan-to-a-formatted-string)):

```
public static string ToReadableString(this TimeSpan span)
{
    string formatted = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}",
        span.Duration().Days > 0 ? string.Format("{0:0} day{1}, ", span.Days, span.Days == 1 ? String.Empty : "s") : string.Empty,
        span.Duration().Hours > 0 ? string.Format("{0:0} hour{1}, ", span.Hours, span.Hours == 1 ? String.Empty : "s") : string.Empty,
        span.Duration().Minutes > 0 ? string.Format("{0:0} minute{1}, ", span.Minutes, span.Minutes == 1 ? String.Empty : "s") : string.Empty,
        span.Duration().Seconds > 0 ? string.Format("{0:0} second{1}", span.Seconds, span.Seconds == 1 ? String.Empty : "s") : string.Empty);

    if (formatted.EndsWith(", ")) formatted = formatted.Substring(0, formatted.Length - 2);

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(formatted)) formatted = "0 seconds";

    return formatted;
}
```

Comment: If the time span is more than a day you will not get the correct value.  For example if that time span is 1 day 5 hours and 6 minutes this will output "05:06:00", not "29:06:00".

Answer (score 2):

You need to format your `TimeSpan` which returns `execution.End - execution.Start` expression with `@"hh\:mm\:ss"` format like;

```
TimeSpan ts = execution.End - execution.Start;
string seconds = ts.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss"); // 00:26:25
```

By the way, there is no `MM` specifier in [custom `TimeSpan` formatting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), it should be lowercase as [`mm` specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#mmSpecifier).

Comment: If the time span is more than a day you will not get the correct value. For example if that time span is 1 day 5 hours and 6 minutes this will output "05:06:00", not "29:06:00"

Comment: What for @Soner was downvoted?

Comment: @juharr Again, OP should consider to say this case can be happen or not. It is good of course to consider it in an answer but a downvote should not be here in such a situation that for a subject that OP doesn't _even_ mentioned in my opinion.