# winforms - gridview cell timespan edit problem

Tags: winforms, datagridview, formatting

I'm following this question for formatting timespan value in the gridview.

[Format TimeSpan in DataGridView column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627922/format-timespan-in-datagridview-column)

I'm diaplying only minutes value in grid as follows

```
DataGridViewColumn idleTimeColumn = myGridView.Columns["IdleTime"];
idleTimeColumn.DefaultCellStyle.FormatProvider = new TimeSpanFormatter();
idleTimeColumn.DefaultCellStyle.Format = "m";
```

This cell is editable, so when I enter 5 (that mean 5 min) in the cell, then it should take it minute, but it take it as day value (ie, 5.00:00:00).

I tried different values for format (mm,%m) but all these gives the same output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to implement the feature to parse an input value.

TimeSpanFormatter can be used to convert a bound TimeSpan data to a formatted string for displaying. But it can't convert an input value to TimeSpan. You have to convert an input value in DataGridView.CellParsing event handler.

The following is the sample code to parse an input value.

**DataGridView.CellParsing event handler**

```
private void dataGridView1_CellParsing(object sender, DataGridViewCellParsingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.DesiredType == typeof(TimeSpan))
    {
        TimeSpanParser parser = new TimeSpanParser();
        e.Value = parser.Parse(e.Value.ToString(), e.InheritedCellStyle.Format);
        e.ParsingApplied = true;
    }
}
```

**TimeSpanParser class**

```
public class TimeSpanParser
{
    private Regex formatParser;

    private List<TimeSpanPart> parts;

    public TimeSpanParser()
    {
        this.formatParser = new Regex("d{1,2}|h{1,2}|m{1,2}|s{1,2}|f{1,7}", RegexOptions.Compiled);
        this.parts = new List<TimeSpanPart>();
    }

    public TimeSpan Parse(string input, string format)
    {
        this.parts.Clear();
        var pattern = this.formatParser.Replace(format, m => ReplaceFormat(m));
        var match = Regex.Match(input, "^" + pattern + "$");

        TimeSpan result = new TimeSpan();
        for (int i = 1; i < match.Groups.Count; i++)
        {
            var value = Convert.ToDouble(match.Groups[i].Value);
            switch (this.parts[i - 1])
            {
                case TimeSpanPart.Day:
                    result = result.Add(TimeSpan.FromDays(value));
                    break;
                case TimeSpanPart.Hour:
                    result = result.Add(TimeSpan.FromHours(value));
                    break;
                case TimeSpanPart.Minute:
                    result = result.Add(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(value));
                    break;
                case TimeSpanPart.Second:
                    result = result.Add(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(value));
                    break;
                case TimeSpanPart.Millisecond:
                    int digit = match.Groups[i].Value.Length;
                    value =value * Math.Pow(10, 3 - digit);
                    result = result.Add(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(value));
                    break;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    private string ReplaceFormat(Match match)
    {
        switch (match.Value)
        {
            case "dd":
            case "d":
                this.parts.Add(TimeSpanPart.Day);
                return "(\\d{1,2})";
            case "hh":
            case "h":
                this.parts.Add(TimeSpanPart.Hour);
                return "(\\d{1,2})";
            case "mm":
            case "m":
                this.parts.Add(TimeSpanPart.Minute);
                return "(\\d{1,2})";
            case "ss":
            case "s":
                this.parts.Add(TimeSpanPart.Second);
                return "(\\d{1,2})";
            case "fffffff":
            case "ffffff":
            case "fffff":
            case "ffff":
            case "fff":
            case "ff":
            case "f":
                this.parts.Add(TimeSpanPart.Millisecond);
                return "(\\d{1,7})";
            default:
                return match.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

**TimeSpanPart enum**

```
public enum TimeSpanPart
{
    Day,
    Hour,
    Minute,
    Second,
    Millisecond,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are handling the cell formatting event properly

[Youe were referring this i guess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627922/format-timespan-in-datagridview-column)

Comment: Yes, I'm handling cell formatting event as specified in that Q

Answer (score -2):

Try [`mm`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372286.aspx) or [`%m`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287.aspx#mSpecifier) instead of `m`; `idleTimeColumn.DefaultCellStyle.Format = "mm";`

Comment: @Sharique: Telling us that it "doesn't work" is not particularly helpful. *Why* didn't it work? What did you see when you tried it, and how was that different from what you expected/desired?