# How can I make this C# function reusable?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am using the code for formatting a timestamp in a datagridview that was provided in this post:

[Format TimeSpan in DataGridView column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627922/format-timespan-in-datagridview-column/3629130#3629130)

... and I'm having an issue with the code to be added to the datagridview_Cellformatting event.

Here's the code in question:

```
private void dataGridView_CellFormatting(object sender, 
                                       DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    var formatter = e.CellStyle.FormatProvider as ICustomFormatter;
    if (formatter != null)
    {
        e.Value = formatter.Format(e.CellStyle.Format, 
                                   e.Value, 
                                   e.CellStyle.FormatProvider);
        e.FormattingApplied = true;
    }
}
```

This works great, but my problem is that given the nature of the databinding I'm doing in my application, I need to call this method on ten different datagridview objects.

You'll notice that this method captures the event target, and that means that I'm currently using ten separate copies of this method in my code. There's got to be a way to consolidate this into a single method that I can call from any of my datagridviews on the CellFormatting event.

Does anyone know how this can be done?

Comment: What do you mean by "captures the event target"? Do you mean in the method name? That's just a method name... you can certainly use the same method for events from multiple objects.

Comment: In the event tab of the properties view for the DataGridView in the Forms Designer, just set the 'Cell Formatting' event to `dataGridView_CellFormatting` for all your DataGridViews. They will then all share the same method for that event.

Comment: Use *inheritance*.  Derive you own class from DataGridView and override the OnCellFormatting() method.  Build.  Use the new control at the top of the toolbox to replace your existing ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Extensions Method.

```
namespace Foo 
{
    public static class DataGridExtensions
    {
        public static void FormatViewCell(this DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
        {
            var formatter = e.CellStyle.FormatProvider as ICustomFormatter;
            if (formatter != null)
            {
                e.Value = formatter.Format(e.CellStyle.Format, 
                                           e.Value, 
                                           e.CellStyle.FormatProvider);
                e.FormattingApplied = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

On data grid CellFormatting

```
using Foo;

private void dataGridView_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    e.FormatViewCell();
}
```

Comment: This did the trick. Many thanks for your help, and for the clear example.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a static method stored in a helper class like this:

```
private static void AddCellFormatting(DataGridView dgView)
{
    dgView.CellFormatting += (sender, e) => 
    {
        var formatter = e.CellStyle.FormatProvider as ICustomFormatter;
        if (formatter != null)
        {
            e.Value = formatter.Format(e.CellStyle.Format, e.Value, e.CellStyle.FormatProvider);
            e.FormattingApplied = true;
        }
    }
}
```

The method can be called from the constructor after the InitializeComponent().

Or simply use your method as a static method and add it from designer.