# How to format TimeSpan to string before .NET 4.0

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, tostring, timespan, string.format

I am compiling in C# using .NET 3.5 and am trying to convert a TimeSpan to a string and format the string. I would like to use

`myString = myTimeSpan.ToString("c");`

however the `TimeSpan.ToString` method does not take a format string as an argument until .NET 4.0 and I am using .NET 3.5.

How then would you format a TimeSpan as a string? My final goal is to display the TimeSpan in format `hh:mm:ss` but am currently receiving `hh:mm:ss:fffffff`.

I have tried using

`myString = string.Format("{0:hh:mm:ss}", myTimeSpan);`

but string.Format is only formatting my DateTime and passing different format strings doesn't work when trying to format a TimeSpan.

Comment: @John: That is not a solution.

Comment: This link might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/840120/timespan-formatting

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/574894/1028323 Answers your question.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

One way could be:

```
TimeSpan ts = DateTime.Now - DateTime.Now.AddHours(-10);
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", ts.TotalHours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds));
```

Result would be something like:

```
09:59:59
```

EDIT:

Or you can try:

```
TimeSpan ts = DateTime.Now - DateTime.Now.AddHours(-10);
DateTime mydate = new DateTime(ts.Ticks);
Console.WriteLine(mydate.ToString(("hh:mm:ss")));
```

Output would be:

```
09:59:59
```

Comment: @Joey, perfect, modified my answer

Answer (score 0):

Better is 24*ts.Days+ts.Hours than ts.TotalHours.
Compare:

```
var ts = TimeSpan.FromHours( 23.9 );
Console.WriteLine( ts );
Console.WriteLine( "{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", ts.TotalHours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds );
Console.WriteLine( "{0}:{1:00}:{2:00}", ts.TotalHours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds );
Console.WriteLine( "{0}:{1:00}:{2:00}", 24*ts.Days+ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds );
```