# C# NAudio Trackbar

Tags: c#, duration, naudio, trackbar

I'm working with a player with NAudio, *refer to http://naudio.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=MP3*.  Everything worked fine but when I'm coding a trackbar, which show the current time and duration, even can seek into any position of the song, so I used timer to update the current time with `mainOutputStream.CurrentTime`,but the format is bad to look,
then I reformatted it like this:

```
string curTime = mainOutputStream.CurrentTime.ToString();
string[] format = curTime.Split(':');
format[2] = format[2].Remove(2);
curTime = format[1] + format[2];
```

but the `format[2] = format[2].Remove(2);` always return an error.
And seems there's no way to get the duration even in timespan but bytes, but I don't like using averageBytePerSecond or anything like this so is there anyway to do these jobs simpler and better?
 *All variable as in the reference above* 

Thanks.

EDIT: Problems solved~ I used this method: 
 Get Duration:

```
string duration = mainOutputStream.TotalTime.ToString("mm\\:ss");
trackPosition.Maximum = (int)mainOutputStream.TotalTime.TotalSeconds;
```

Get Current Time:

```
string curTime = mainOutputStream.CurrentTime.ToString("mm\\:ss");
trackPosition.Value = (int)mainOutputStream.CurrentTime.TotalSeconds;
```

Comment: What type of object is CurrentTime and what format does it reture and what format do you require?

Comment: it's a `timespan`, I'm putting it into trackbar so I need `int`.

Comment: yes, but I still need to label it out like this `02:44`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
string curTimeString = mainOutputStream.CurrentTime.ToString("mm\\:ss");
int curTimeSeconds =  (int)mainOutputStream.CurrentTime.TotalSeconds;
```

the first one is only formated for minutes and seconds, if your audio tracks are larger you will have to add different formatting.

More info on that can be found here: [Timespan formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840120/timespan-formatting)

Comment: CurrentTime.TotalSeconds is 'double', and there's decimal behind, anyway to remove it?

Comment: opps, sorry I forgot to cast as int, fixed above

Comment: woah, worked like god! 
How about the duration part? mainOutputStream.Length only gives the bytes, any way to calculate the duration but not average bytes/sec?

EDIT: Just found out that there's an `TotalTime` object there, a timespan, good.

Comment: erm... got a little prob.
            `string totalTime = mainOutputStream.TotalTime.TotalSeconds.ToString("ss");`                       
            `int totalTimeSec = int.Parse(totalTime);`
This two don't work...

Comment: `mainOutputStream.TotalTime.TotalSeconds.ToString()` you dont need the"ss" format for TotalSeconds