# Mapping a database value to a TimeSpan using dbml

Tags: sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql, timespan

I need to store a time offset in a database column (for example, 12:25 AM, just the time, no date).

I would like to use the nice data visual modeling capabilities in Visual Studio 2008 to generate dbml and the code to go with it. The database is Sql Server 2005.

Since a TimeSpan is essentially an Int64 (aka long) containing the number of ticks, I tried to store that long in the database.

If however I specify that the column should map to a property of type TimeSpan, Visual Studio reports :

> Warning : The custom tool 'MSLinqToSQLGenerator' failed.  Unspecified error

To work around this I've mapped the database value to an internal property and I've added a partial class that implements property accessors that convert the integer value from the database to TimeSpan and back.

Is there a way to enable the correct code to be generated for this property? Or is there better way to store a timespan in a SqlServer 2005 database that allows easier access using dbml?

Comment: Just curious, why would you only store the time in the database and not the date? SQL 2005 does not support storing just the Time alone.

Comment: My application involves a daily schedule with activities that occur on specific times, every day. So date has no relevance, just the time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Also faced this problem some time ago.

As I understood there is no direct resolution with `SQL Server 2005`, so I used a trick:

there is `Duration` column (which actually should store a .NET `TimeStamp` data type) in the database of type `BigInt NOT NULL`. Here is dbml definition:

```
<Column Name="Duration" 
    Member="DurationInternal" 
    AccessModifier="Protected" 
    Type="System.Int64" 
    DbType="BigInt NOT NULL" 
    CanBeNull="false" />
```

I set this class property as `protected` which mean I don't want the user of my class access this property directly and made a `public` wrapper for this property in partial class:

```
    #region Properties
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the audio duration.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The duration.</value>
    public TimeSpan Duration
    {
        get
        {
            return TimeSpan.FromTicks(this.DurationInternal);
        }
        set
        {
            this.DurationInternal = value.Ticks;
        }
    }
    #endregion
```

So the user of my class has a easy-to-use property instead of a lot of `long` to `TimeSpan` conversions.

Hope, this helps.

Comment: This is pretty much what I ended up with too. See my comment on xoxo's answer.

Answer (score 3):

I have tried to do this before, with epic failures. I found that even though I am not using the Date part of the DateTime in the database, I discovered that submitting the entire Date and Time to the database allowed me to provide all the functionality with the Time i needed.

You can use the ToShortTimeString() to display just the time in your application. Having the full date in with the time allows you to do true time calculations if you ever needed to do that, such as determine the timespan between a start time and stop time. Because the ticks involved with the time span include the date, there should be no reason to go through the extra trouble to just store the time in the database.

I know this is not really what you were hoping for, but probably the easiest solution for your needs, and this comes from hours of banging my head experience in trying to do the same thing.

Comment: I'm seeing the first signs of trouble; just tried formatting a TimeSpan. That's a pain already... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574881/how-can-i-string-format-a-timespan-object-with-a-custom-format-in-net

Answer (score 1):

You can map the TimeSpan data type to the Sql 'Time' data type (thus avoiding any nasty implementation issues).
However the following requirements must be met:

1. Your codebase must be running on
   .Net 3.5 sp1
2. The Sql Database must
   be running on Sql 2008 (the TIME
   datatype is only available in 2008).

For clarification read this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882662.aspx

Comment: Actually, what I did was store the TimeSpan value as an integer value. .NET uses an Int64 value (Ticks) to store both TimeSpan and DateTime values. While this means I can't use date and time functions in SQL but it does allow me to sort on the TimeSpan column. As an added bonus, it takes care of the resolution difference between .NET DateTime/TimeSpan and SQLServer datetime.