# How do I create a Descriptive DateConverter in C#?

Tags: c#, datetime, twitter, datediff

I have a DateConverter class that does all the basics.  However, I want to add another type to it.  I want to be able to have a 'Descriptive' type that returns the difference between the date and DateTime.Now formatted as a string.

IE: "seconds ago", "7 minutes ago", "8 hours ago"

Whichever the larger increment is.

I suppose the only thing I am missing is figuring out how to get the difference between the two dates in seconds. C# is still a little new to me.

Comment: You can just follow this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11/how-do-i-calculate-relative-time‎

Comment: Thanks Lenin, combined with the answers and your link, I was able to complete the converter I was trying to make!

Comment: possible duplicate of [TimeSpan to friendly string library (C#)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138723/timespan-to-friendly-string-library-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can subtract two datetime objects and it will return [**`TimeSpan`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx)
and you can get [**`Seconds`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.seconds.aspx) property of TimeSpan

```
var timespan = (datetime1 - datetime2);
var seconds = timespan.Seconds;
var Minutes = timespan.Minutes;
var hours = timespan.Hours;
```

> I suppose the only thing I am missing is figuring out how to get the
>   difference between the two dates in seconds.

then you want `timespan.TotalSeconds`

Answer (score 0):

what about using an extension method instead, like

```
public static string FromNowFormatted(this DateTime date)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();

    var t = DateTime.Now - date;

    var dic = new Dictionary<string, int>
              {
                  {"years", (int)(t.Days / 365)},
                  {"months", (int)(t.Days / 12)},
                  {"days", t.Days},
                  {"hours", t.Hours},
                  {"minutes", t.Minutes},
                  {"seconds", t.Seconds},
              };

    bool b = false;
    foreach (var e in dic)
    {                
        if (e.Value > 0 || b)
        {
            var v = e.Value;
            var k = v == 1 ? e.Key.TrimEnd('s') : e.Key ;

            sb.Append(v + " " + k + "\n");
            b = true;
        }
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

[demo](http://ideone.com/yeiMBS)

Note: there are some things with this code you'll need to fix-up such as the ways years and months are calculated.

Edit: you could use Noda Time's Period.Between() which calculates the difference and then just have an extension method as above, that would simply format it in a similar way. see the secion "Finding a period between two values" [here](http://noda-time.googlecode.com/hg/docs/userguide/arithmetic.html) for more info.