# using timspan get only time without millisecond from datetime

Tags: vb.net

I have Vb.net code like this:

```
Dim requestddate As DateTime = DateTime.Now   
Dim rdate As Date = requestddate.Date 
Dim rtime As TimeSpan = requestddate.TimeOfDay
```

In `rtime` varibale I want to get only time like: `03:15:10` (hour,minute,second).

But now I am getting `rtime` value as `03:15:10.7929313`.

Comment: Why is that a problem? When you want to display the `TimeSpan`, use a format string that doesn't include the milliseconds.

Comment: I given code like this:

Comment: Dim rtime As TimeSpan = requestddate.TimeOfDay.ToString("hh:mm:ss")  but still getting error

Comment: Sure you are. A `TimeSpan` is not a `string`. Use the `ToString` where you need to _display_ the `TimeSpan` value.

Comment: can u please show how i can write the code for the same

Comment: You are making the classic mistake of not documenting your question well enough.  "but still getting error" doesn't help us help you.  Some likelihood that you are not using .NET 4, check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2456543/17034)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a fact, that [`TimeSpan(Int32, Int32, Int32)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bk8a3558.aspx) can take more then `60` as `seconds` parameter value:

```
Dim rtime As New TimeSpan(0, 0, CInt(requestddate.TimeOfDay.TotalSeconds))
```

Answer (score 1):

A `TimeSpan` contains [all properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan_properties.aspx), there is no way to remove the milliseconds for instance. If you instead want to display this `TimeSpan` as `String` you can use `ToString`:

```
requestddate.TimeOfDay.ToString("hh\:mm\:ss"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Dim requestddate As DateTime = DateTime.Now
    Dim rdate As Date = requestddate.Date
    Dim rtime As TimeSpan = requestddate.TimeOfDay

    Dim t As String = rtime.Hours & ":" & rtime.Minutes & ":" & rtime.Seconds
```