# Convert decimal hours into HH:ii:ss greater than 24 hours

Tags: c#, rdlc

I have a decimal value (64.17 hours) and need to convert this to a timestamp of hours, minutes and seconds but the hours value should show 64 not 16.

It should also not show the microseconds so 64.17 would be displayed as

64:10:12

Anyone help me on this?  I also need to put it in an aggregate function (average in this case)

```
TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan();
            ts.Add(TimeSpan.FromHours(ncr_time_lost));
            Console.WriteLine(ncr_time_lost + " = " + TimeSpan.FromHours(ncr_time_lost).ToString());

            return TimeSpan.FromHours(ncr_time_lost);
```

Comment: [Standard TimeSpan Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372286.aspx) & [Custom TimeSpan Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update Working Code**
Add the below to the code part for the report

```
Public Function TimeSpanToString(source as Timespan) as String
    Dim result As String
    result = Convert.ToInt32(source.TotalHours).ToString() & ":" & source.Minutes.ToString() & ":" & source.Seconds

    return result
End Function
```

Here is the answer with an example: [TimeSpan.FromHours Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.fromhours.aspx).

**Update**:
The format "64:10:12" can be done with the following code:

```
static string TimeSpanToString(TimeSpan source)
{
    string result = string.Format("{0}:{1}:{2}",
        (int)source.TotalHours,
        source.Minutes,
        source.Seconds);
    return result;
}
```

**Update**:
Don't know whether it's correct, but try the following to use it from RDLC:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public TimeSpan Time { get; set; }

    public string FormattedTime
    {
       get { return TimeSpanToString(Time); }
    }

    private static string TimeSpanToString(TimeSpan source)
    {
        // Code.
    }
}
```

Then try to get it from the report as `"=Fields!FormattedDate.Value"`.

Comment: How would this be used in a report?

Comment: Thanks Serge I'm new to RDLC do I just put this in the report code and call it?  If so it comes back with a custom code error

Comment: @Neo, actually, I've not tested the code with RDLC, just a sketch (see the post update).

Comment: Thanks Serge, Your answer pointed me in the right direction, it appears the RDLC code is VB :( I've added the working code to your post and marked it as the right answer

Answer (score 4):

Why not just use the [TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx) structure?  Yes it keeps track of days, but there's also a TotalHours property that should give you everything your looking for.

You can also do any averaging calculations on the TotalMilliseconds property.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574881/how-can-i-string-format-a-timespan-object-with-a-custom-format-in-net) for more information on formatting the TimeSpan.

Comment: My issue is formatting it within the report which keeps coming back as an error!  I have in the class a timespan created using the code I just added to the question but when I show it on the report it comes back with #Error