# Converting Date to hours in VB

Tags: vb.net, datetime, computation

How can I compute date to hours? For example I want to compute how many hours past during `July 23 to the current date(July 25 in our country).`

Outputting it like this:

```
Total Hours past: 48 Hours
```

Comment: You care about the time part as well or only date? i.e. The hours will be different depending on what time on 23rd July you compare current date time with

Comment: [TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx) will give you minutes, hours, milliseconds, whatever you want  see also [How to format a TimeSpan object in .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/q/574881/1070452)

Comment: @shree.pat18 both actually, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @shree.pat18 Can it actually convert days into hours?

Comment: @Plutonix I'm trying to compute the intervals between 2 dates then converting the answer into hours.

Comment: the third example snippet in the TimeSpan link shows how to subtract dates and get the interval. please show what you have tried and where the dates come from.

Comment: [DateDiff](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b5xbyt6f(v=vs.90).aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect there is more lurking below the surface like how you get the dates into your code.  If one date originates from another country, you will have to take that into consideration.  Hard to be clearer without code.

```
Dim thisDate As DateTime = #2/10/2010#
Dim thatDate As DateTime = #10/21/2013#

Dim ts1 As TimeSpan = thatDate.Subtract(thisDate)
' or:
' Dim ts1 As TimeSpan = thatDate - thisDate
Console.WriteLine("{0} Days or {1} hours have passed", 
        ts1.TotalDays, ts1.TotalHours)
```

Output:

```
1349 Days or 32376 hours have passed
```

Comment: Sorry for not showing any code I'm at my code at another workstation

Comment: Can the days be converted into hours without rounding it off?

Comment: days, hours, seconds, milliseconds, years, months, clock ticks - all already computed for you

Comment: I mean the output is it possible to become hours? Sorry, I'm not familiar with vb.

Comment: what do you mean "become hours"?  timespan tells you the span of time (in all manner of increments) between 2 dates.  if the dates are 2 days apart it will be 48 hours

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub days_calc_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim d1 As Date = "24/07/2014" ' From date
    Dim d2 As Date = "24/08/2014" ' To date
    MsgBox("Date difference in days : " & (d2 - d1).TotalDays & "Days")
    MsgBox("Date difference in hours : " & (d2 - d1).TotalHours & "Hours")
    MsgBox("Date difference in minutes : " & (d2 - d1).TotalMinutes & "Minutes")
End Sub
```

Comment: Can it converted to hours?