# Binding two dropdownlist in ASP.net Web Forms C# into one database entity

Tags: c#, datetime, drop-down-menu, binding, webforms

I am building a C# application with  ASP.Net Web Form having two dropdown list. One list is for selecting the hour and the other list is for selecting the minute. Once both dropdownlist are selected I would like to put them together to display as a single unit of time. For instance, if someone was to select 9 as the hour  from dropdownlist1 and 25 as the minute from dropdownlist2, the two selections would store in a database as one unit of time 9:25 and could be selected from the database as a 9:25.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a week late but since your question didn't get any attention, so..

I assume you already filled your dropdownlist controls, let's start to get their selected item values;

```
string hour = dropdownlist1.SelectedItem.Text;
string minute = dropdownlist2.SelectedItem.Text;
```

Now these `hour` and `minutes` strings will be probably `9` and `25`. Since the situation we talk about is to get and save a *time interval*, it will be good to parse it to [`TimeSpan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.timespan.aspx) first which is exactly what this for in .NET Framework.

```
TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.Parse(string.Format("{0}:{1}", hour, minute), 
                             CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

With this operation, we will have a `TimeSpan` which has `9` hour and `25` minutes. And it seems as `{09:25:00}` in debugger.

If you use SQL Server, it has a [`time` type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677243.aspx) which is [mapped](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131092%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) with `TimeSpan` in CLR data type. You can directly insert this type of data to your column.

```
using(var con = new SqlConnection(conString))
using(var cmd = con.CreateCommand())
{
     cmd.CommandText = "insert into MyTable(myColumn) VALUES (@myValue)";
     cmd.Parameters.Add("@myValue", SqlDbType.Time).Value = ts;
     con.Open();
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Now, in your table you have a value from `00:00:00.0000000` to `23:59:59.9999999` range. When you get this value as a `TimeSpan` from your database, you can format it to see it as 9:25 as a textual representation.

```
string s = ts.ToString("h\\:mm"); // s will be 9:25
```

But remember, [`TimeSpan.ToString(string)` overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992632%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) came with .NET 4 version. If you use lower version, you can check this question;

- [How can I String.Format a TimeSpan object with a custom format in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574881/how-can-i-string-format-a-timespan-object-with-a-custom-format-in-net)