# Displaying a formatted TimeSpan as string

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, timespan

I'd like to display a TimeSpan value, formatted as mm:ss (minutes, seconds).

The code currently performs this like this:

```
var timeSpan = GetTimeUntilNextEvent();
var str = DateTime.MinValue.Add(timeSpan).ToString(@"mm\:ss");
```

I wonder whether that is correct code. I saw other samples that show this technique, but I am not really sure what is the reason for adding something to the MinValue of DateTime.

Why cannot this code be used ? It seems to product a valid result.

```
var str = DateTime.FromBinary(0).Add(timeSpan).ToString(@"mm\:ss");
```

Comment: What `GetTimeUntilNextEvent` method do? What do you try to achieve exactly?

Comment: `DateTime.Add` returns `DateTime`, so this question is not about a formatted `TimeSpan` but `DateTime`. For thast reason you  don't need `.ToString(@"mm\:ss")`  but you can use `.ToString("mm:ss")`.

Comment: `DateTime.MinValue` and `DateTime.FromBinary(0)` are exactly the same.

Comment: Well, technically adding a negative timespan to MinValue causes an exception, which is exactly what i'm trying to prevent.

Comment: You want to prevent a negative time span?

Comment: I just realized that it's exactly the same thing, and i probably really should just normalize to start at 0....

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I String.Format a TimeSpan object with a custom format in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574881/how-can-i-string-format-a-timespan-object-with-a-custom-format-in-net)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need DateTime to format a TimeSpan.
You could simply use the timespan ToString() method:

```
TimeSpan timeSpan = new TimeSpan(5, 12, 2);
String str = timeSpan.ToString(@"mm\:ss"));
```

Also see [Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd992632(v=vs.110).aspx).