# How to countdown in seconds from minutes using a countdown timer

Tags: c#, windows, timer, windows-phone-8.1

Currently developing a simple windows phone 8.1 silverlight app with an implemented countdown time. I have it working where I can input a set amount of minutes and it countdowns fine but what I am wanting to happen is for a user to input an amount of minutes and to countdown in seconds from there, for example it is currently 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5 when 10 seconds is input.

What I want to happen is that the user inputs 5 and it counts down like so:
4:59
4:58
4:57

This is my current code:

```
    timer = new DispatcherTimer();
    timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
    timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
    basetime = Convert.ToInt32(tbxTime.Text);;
    tbxTime.Text = basetime.ToString();
    timer.Start();
}


void timer_Tick(object sender, object e)
{
    basetime = basetime - 1;
    tbxTime.Text = basetime.ToString();
    if (basetime == 0)
    {
        timer.Stop();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can keep most of your existing code if you just make `basetime` a `TimeSpan` instead of an `int`. It's easy to set its value from Minutes or Seconds via the appropriate static method.

```
var basetime = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
```

Then you can subtract one second from it like this:

```
basetime -= TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
```

And display it like this:

```
tbxTime.Text = basetime.ToString(@"m\:ss");
```

Finally, comparing it to zero is also trivial:

```
if (basetime <= TimeSpan.Zero)
```

See [Custom TimeSpan Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for more display options.

Comment: Seems like you have been faster by 92 OP timer's ticks. You have my vote.

Comment: This has worked the best so far, with no breaks when implemented. I entered 5 into the tbxTime textbox and it only counted down to 4:59 then stopped, have I missed anything?

Comment: @user4682589 It's hard to say if you had missed anything. Try to debug your code and find what is wrong.

Comment: ok thankyou for your time, I shall play around abit and post up the results, thanks again

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just make use of suitable formatting of *TimeSpan* class (you will surely [find many examples on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/574881/2681948)). The easy example can look like this (I assume that you have a *TextBox* where you enter time and *TextBlock* which shows counter);

```cs
DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer() { Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1) };
TimeSpan time;
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    timer.Tick += (sender, e) =>
        {
            time -= TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
            if (time <= TimeSpan.Zero) timer.Stop();
            myTextBlock.Text = time.ToString(@"mm\:ss");
        };
}
private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{ time = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(int.Parse((sender as TextBox).Text)); }

private void startBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{ timer.Start(); }
```

Note that this is a very simple example. You should also think if *DispatcherTimer* is a good idea - it works on dispatcher, so in case you have some big job running on main UI thread it may not count the time properly. In this case you may think of using different timer, for example *System.Threading.Timer*, this runs on separate thread, so you will have to update your UI through Dispatcher.

Comment: Great info about the `DispatchTimer`.

Comment: @CoderDennis This is the reason I've left this answer - it provides some additional information which may help somebody, without this I would delete my answer as there is no need to duplicate answers :]