# Double Data Type representation of 24 hour time to the 24-hour Format time

Tags: c#, mongodb, datetime, datetime-format, data-conversion

All:

Here are the details associated with my development environment:

- Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2013
- MongoDB version 3.0.0

In my MongoDB Database, there is collection called BusSchedule with the following fields

```
BusSchedule
-Double StartTime
-Double EndTime
-String 24hourFormatStartTime
-String 24hourFormatEndTime
```

Here are some typical values that might exist

```
StartTime = 6.5
EndTime = 9.5
24hourFormatStartTime = "06:30"
24hourFormatEndTime = "09:30"

StartTime = 8.5
EndTime = 14.25
24hourFormatStartTime = "08:30"
24hourFormatEndTime = "14:15"
```

I was wondering if Microsoft had some kind of existing library that could easily
convert the Double Data Type representation of 24 hour time to the 24-hour Format time.

```
StartTime = 8.5  -------translated to-----> 24hourFormatStartTime = "08:30"
EndTime = 14.25  -------translated to-----> 24hourFormatEndTime = "14:15"

StartTime = 6.5 -------translated to-----> 24hourFormatStartTime = "06:30"
EndTime = 9.5 -------translated to-----> 24hourFormatEndTime = "09:30"
```

I don't want to waste time writing code to do the aforementioned translation.
Could someone please tell me if Microsoft or some 3rd-party open source library will handle the aforementioned requirement?

Comment: You can read these values on C# side as `System.Double` or `System.String`?

Comment: The Double type is associated with StartTime and EndTime on the C# side.  The 24hourFormatStartTime and 24hourFormatEndTime are associated with String on the C# side.  Am I answering your question properly?

Comment: I know their associations but _can_ you read this `6.5` or `14.25` values from your mongodb and assign it C# double variable like `/* read this value from db */ double d = 14.25`? Or are you asking how to read this values from mongodb and assign it?

Comment: I already can read the StartTime and EndTime values from MongoDB and place them in double variables.  how  can I convert it to a string version of 24-hour Format time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I already can read the StartTime and EndTime values from MongoDB and
>   place them in double variables. how can I convert it to a string
>   version of 24-hour Format time?

Then you can use this double values to generate a [`TimeSpan`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.timespan.aspx) and get their string representation using `TimeSpan.ToString()` method and`hh\\:mm` format.

```
TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromHours(14.25);
```

[image]

Then

```
Console.WriteLine(ts.ToString("hh\\:mm")); // 14:15
```

Be aware, this code is for .Net 4.0 or above. If you have .Net 3.5 and below, you need to use [`string.Format` as explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/574894/447156).