# How to format a TimeSpan object

Tags: asp.net, embed, eval, timespan, string.format

I need to show inside a repeater the remaining time for a sale object to end, which has DateTime ends property.

Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/4386305/8383866 I tried to make it work but I'm getting:

> ) expected.

But I'm sure there is no parenthesis missing.

```
Ends in: <%#string.Format("{0:hh\\:mm\\:ss}", (TimeSpan)(DateTime.Now - (DateTime)Eval("finaliza")));%>
```

Comment: Try changing code like: `<%#string.Format("{0:hh\\:mm\\:ss}", DateTime.Now.Subtract(DateTime.Parse(Eval("finaliza"))));%>
`

Comment: Thanks but same message error shown, I think I'm going to add that TimeSpan on the object itself and then simply bind it on the repeater.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should convert Eval("finaliza") to DateTime with the Convert.ToDateTime method.

Like this

```
<%#string.Format("{0:hh\\:mm\\:ss}", (TimeSpan)(DateTime.Now - Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("finaliza"))));%>
```

Comment: Thanks but same message error shown, I think I'm going to add that TimeSpan on the object itself and then simply bind it on the repeater.