# PowerShell - Multiple Get-Date calls return different time formats / cultures

Tags: powershell, datetime, culture

I am currently working on a powershell script where I need to measure the duration between the start and the end of the script execution. After searching for a while I decided to use this approach to do so: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61432373/11425760
I have one Get-Date call to get the start time at the beginning of the script execution and another Get-Date call right before the script execution is about to end:

```
$StartTime = Get-Date

# Script logic...

$EndTime = Get-Date
$Duration = New-TimeSpan -Start $StartTime -End $EndTime

$Day = switch ($Duration.Days)
{
    0 { $null; break }
    1 { "{0} day," -f $Duration.Days; break }
    Default {"{0} days," -f $Duration.Days}
}

$Hour = switch ($Duration.Hours)
{
    #0 { $null; break }
    1 { "{0} hour," -f $Duration.Hours; break }
    Default { "{0} hours," -f $Duration.Hours }
}

$Minute = switch ($Duration.Minutes)
{
    #0 { $null; break }
    1 { "{0} minute," -f $Duration.Minutes; break }
    Default { "{0} minutes," -f $Duration.Minutes }
}

$Second = switch ($Duration.Seconds)
{
    #0 { $null; break }
    1 { "{0} second" -f $Duration.Seconds; break }
    Default { "{0} seconds" -f $Duration.Seconds }
}

Write-Host "The script execution took: $Day $Hour $Minute $Second"
Write-Host "Script execution ended"
```

While this seemed to work fine when I implemented it, I suddenly started running into a problem where for some reason I get a "ParameterBindingException" when calling New-TimeSpan, telling me that the value for the "End" argument (e.g. "08/19/2020 08:54:51") cannot be converted into the type System.DateTime. When I then look at the start and end time I provided, they are both printed in different formats despite them both coming from a Get-Date call. For example, the `end time` gets printed as

```
"08/19/2020 08:54:51"
```

and the `start time` as

```
"Mittwoch, 19. August 2020 08:54:08"
```

(german format). This only seems to happen when I run the script for the first time because as soon as I run it again, the error no longer occurs. What I don't understand is: After checking both the start and the end time, the start time was (as expected) a DateTime object but the end time was just a string, despite both values coming from a Get-Date call. Why does this even happen to begin with and how can I avoid running into this problem (or similar problems)?

Comment: Did you try to create a culture object with a defined format and use it all along? Like this:

`$en = New-Object system.globalization.cultureinfo(“en-US”)`
So you can run this to get the date from this culture
`Get-Date -Format ($en.DateTimeFormat.FullDateTimePattern)`

Comment: @Kluk No, I didn't but I am also not changing anything regarding the culture during the script execution, so it makes no sense to me why I suddenly get something different when calling Get-Date. I also just noticed that when the problem occurs, the start time is a DateTime object while the end time is actually just a string, despite them both coming from a Get-Date call.

Comment: and are you sure that these Get-Date are executed on the same system? Not on a remote server or into an `Invoke-Command` or anything like this? If you run `Get-Culture`, do you get only one format? Maybe you can show us the bit of code which causes this issue.

Comment: @Kluk Yes, I am not doing anything like that in my script and I executed it locally on my system. When I run `Get-Culture` I only get the culture "de-DE". I will add the code in my question.

Comment: It works perfectly on my side. But maybe you can try to cast your variables as datetime:
`[datetime]$StartTime = Get-Date`

Comment: The above works perfectly for me, Could you please also confirm if the above is the complete entirety of your script?, I assume you have some additional logic where `# Script logic...` is? Is it possible you are using very similarly named variables? (possibly one is being converted to a string type using `.tostring()` method etc?)

Comment: @CraftyB Yes, I noticed that I already use the $EndTime variable for something else in the script, but shouldn't this make no difference considering that I just assign the result of the Get-Date call to it afterwards? Or does it matter for some reason what value was assigned to the variable before that? I just renamed the $StartTime and $EndTime variables to something that isn't used anywhere else and now it seems to work fine.

Comment: you can force the format in the start and in the end... using `ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm)` for example, then convert it back... this way the format will always be the same

Comment: You are correct with regards to how variables do get stored and the reassigning it should wipe over the value regardless of their content or type. However I have just tested something, are you casting the initial value of `$EndTime` e.g. `[string]$EndTime = "BLAH"`, as when testing this seems to make the variable persist as a string type even when using `get-date` to assign the value I am getting the same result as you that the format of the value is a string.

Comment: I don't think you can reassign a different type into a variable like this. It's probably better to clear it or delete it before. You can use `Clear-Variable` to remove the data within the variable or `Remove-Variable` which will remove the data and the variable itself. Example: `Remove-Variable -Name 'EndTime'` (no $ symbol)

Comment: But regarding this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_variables?view=powershell-7 you shouldn't have to do anything before changing the type. But I already had this case into functions and I had to clear it before re-using it. Is this part of code written into a function?

Comment: @Kluk No, it isn't written inside a function.

Comment: A simple solution is when you are re declaring the variable declare them like this: `[DateTime]$StartTime = Get-Date` & `[DateTime]$EndTime = Get-Date` this will force them to a DateTime data type and should work as you expect.

Comment: @CraftyB I already advised this and I'm still waiting for a feedback. I also think it should work.

Comment: As I said, it already works after renaming the variables so I cannot test if the suggestion to cast the variables as datetime helps or not.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend ditching the approach and use the StopWatch instead.

Just create and start a stopwatch in the begining of the exection and at the end stop it and you have the object with the time to look at.

```
$stopwatch =  [system.diagnostics.stopwatch]::StartNew()

$stopwatch.Stop()

$stopwatch
```

This will output:

> IsRunning Elapsed          ElapsedMilliseconds ElapsedTicks
>
> ---
>
> ```
> False 00:00:00.0009000                   0         9000
> ```

Or you can get this:

```
$stopwatch.Elapsed





Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 0
Milliseconds      : 1
Ticks             : 16324
TotalDays         : 1,88935185185185E-08
TotalHours        : 4,53444444444444E-07
TotalMinutes      : 2,72066666666667E-05
TotalSeconds      : 0,0016324
TotalMilliseconds : 1,6324
```

But you can format it in any way you want too.